# How to put images in a linked list in python

Tags: python, linked-list

I have created a class Node having two data members: data and next.
I have created another class LinkedList to having a data member: head
Now I want to store an image in the node but I have no idea how to do it. The syntax for performing this operation would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

PIL is the Python Imaging Library which provides the python interpreter with image editing capabilities.
USE **from PIL import Image** after installing. 
**Windows: Download the appropriate Pillow package according to your python version. Make sure to download according to the python version you have**.
**pip install Pillow** for Linux users.
Then u can easily add image to your linked list by assigning it to a variable

Comment: Okay. I will try this. Thanks